# Can I change this search bar's resolution?

Tags: brave

Is there any way to resize these title bar resolution of all the browser? THey are too much small... Pleas anyone help..

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GeAt.png)

Comment: It may be better to ask at the Brave support site. https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us

Comment: But the problem is happening with chrome and all other browsers too..

Comment: Where does it say that in your question? Please edit the question and add this info.

Comment: You should provide much more information. For example, the OS version you have, the browser and version you're trying to use, do you have HDPI display, have you already adjusted subpixel antialiasing, which font you have selected for your desktop environment? It looks like you just have some low quality font selected as default for your desktop environment.